# Convert bytes to float values

Tags: c#, byte

I need to convert 28 byte value to a 7 float values, each 4 bytes denote 1 float value. I have to implement this in C#. I searched for lot of solutions, but most of them were in C/Java.

Comment: Are you looking for a conversion like this byte b = 28;  float f = (float) b;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
System.BitConverter.ToSingle(..)
```

Like this:

```
float f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7;  
f1 = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bytearr,0);  
f2 = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bytearr,4);  
f3 = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bytearr,8);  
...  
f7 = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bytearr,24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
byte b;
float f;
f = (float)b;
```

Comment: A comment would have been more useful than a downvote