# Parsing byte array that contains different data types and able to get each value correctly using Java

Tags: java, arrays, io

I am new to Java, working on byte arrays.

I am having a Blob which is created in Database, which contains a double and float value. Now I have to read that into a byte array and should able to get the float and double separately.

I am read the blob information into the byte array like so:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);

byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int)file.length()];

fin.read(fileContent);
```

and reading the byte array like

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++)

{

  System.out.println("bit " + i + "= " + fileContent[i]);

  }
```

This is giving byte

```
   bit 0= -57
   bit 1= -16
   bit 2= -90
   bit 3= -109
   bit 4= 66
   bit 5= -90
   bit 6= 116
   bit 7= -25
   bit 8= -100
```

Comment: how many bytes are used for each field? 4 bytes for each ? Usually  float is 4 and double is 8

Comment: How will you know what type to read?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readDouble()

Comment: I will have the information about the bytes of each field.. so i may know the no of byte that i might read. so please help me about the logic to read the byte array..

Comment: if you want to get a float from an array of bytes, pick out the right 4 bytes (this logic comes from what you know about the byte array), and convert them to a float using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773520/convert-bytes-to-float-values . Do the same for all data types.

Comment: Hey sorry.. can tell me how can i pick right 4 bytes at time so that i can get the value of the data type.

Comment: Conversions are not available in java. any other suggestions or ways to achieve the same..

Answer (score 0):

You may use [longBitsToDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29) and [intBitsToFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) to convert an `long` (64 bits) or an `int`(32 bits). However, you must take care if the floats have a binary layout matching that of Java; and you have take care to assemble the bytes read from the blob in the proper order. (using `<<` operator).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and least error prone way to do this is by using a ByteBuffer. Here's an example containing two test cases, the first creates a binary file and the second one reads it. Note that you can set your byte encoding to little endian or big endian.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class ByteStreamWriteRead {
  @Test
  public void write() throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

    System.out.println("Putting: " + Math.PI + ", " + (float) Math.PI);
    buffer.putDouble(Math.PI);
    buffer.putFloat((float) Math.PI);

    File file = new File("C:/tmp/file.bin");
    file.createNewFile();

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
      fos.write(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.position());
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void read() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:/tmp/file.bin");
    byte[] a = new byte[32];
    if (file.exists()) {
      try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        fis.read(a);
      }

      ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(a);
      buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

      System.out.println(buffer.getDouble());
      System.out.println(buffer.getFloat());
    } else {
      System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
    }
  }
}
```

Just a note: the examples above do NOT show the most efficient way to read or write a file. You should use a buffered reader/writer and reuse the ByteBuffer to read a chunk of bytes at a time. That's application specific. The example above only shows the logic to use the ByteBuffer and the right byte encoding.